# All react-native-paper components throw type error regarding Accessibility API

Tags: react-native, typescript-typings, react-tsx, react-native-paper, accessibility-api

In my react app using `react-native-paper` with `typescript` all the paper components throw the type Error;

> type '`The props used`' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<`Component Related Props` & { style?: StyleProp; theme: Theme; } & RefAttributes<{}>, "ref" | "onLayout" | "style" | "testID" | ... 32 more ... | "key">': accessibilityComponentType, accessibilityTraits

for instance, if I use the Text component of react-native-paper like

```
<Text>something</Text>
```

the error is : `Type '{ children: string; }' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<TextProps & { style?: StyleProp<TextStyle>; theme: Theme; } & RefAttributes<{}>, "ref" | "onLayout" | "style" | "testID" | ... 32 more ... | "key">': accessibilityComponentType, accessibilityTraits`

Using  `<Text accessibilityComponentType accessibilityTraits> something </Text>`

removes the error and it is the situation for almost all components.

env:

```
    "react": "16.13.1",
    "react-native": "0.63.4",
    "react-native-paper": "^4.7.1",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^8.0.0",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.63.2",
```

Comment: I had a similar problem, not for all components though. It had an easy fix: Change `<Button {...props} ></Button >  `to `<Button {...props} > </Button >  `

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be an issue with @types/react-native or react-native-paper, there are open issues for this problem on react-native-paper issues, this hasn't been fixed however there is a temporary workaround. Installing this exact version of @types/react-native fixes the problem.

```
npm i @types/react-native@0.63.0
```

https://github.com/callstack/react-native-paper/issues/1971